# Uber developer API, ride request payment collection

Tags: uber-api

i want to develop an App with Uber API to provide a service, collect payments from the customer and book the ride for them automatically through my App. Is it possible to use feature like book for a friend and pay for the ride from a single developer account? or does the customer have to pay for the ride separately ?